# When will the banner go away?

Tags: discussion

> Well, look what we have here... A *real* Stack Overflow meta, for *real* Stack Overflow questions. [See the blog for details](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/04/announcing-the-launch-of-meta-stack-exchange/).

This is starting to get a little bit annoying. When will it go away?

Comment: Some folks don't visit Meta very often, and they will have *absolutely no idea what happened, if the banner is not there.*  My recommendation is that we keep it there for at least 30 days.

Comment: The old MSO was very intimidating for many users, so the fact that it has changed may be very welcome to them. It takes time to spread the word as not everyone signs in every day

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if the community team has plans to renew it, but currently the banner is set to expire on May 1 at 10:00 AM UTC.

As Robert notes in the comments, a lot of people don't *frequent* Meta Stack Overflow and we are trying to make as many users aware of the MSO/MSE split and its implications as possible.